Why is there a loss of energy in matter.js newtons cradle?
In the live simulation available at https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#newtonsCradle, how can the issue of energy loss be resolved? Despite setting friction to zero, energy loss still occurs.
Does anyone have an idea?
/**
* Creates a composite with a Newton's Cradle setup of bodies and constraints.
* @method newtonsCradle
* @param {number} xx
* @param {number} yy
* @param {number} number
* @param {number} size
* @param {number} length
* @return {composite} A new composite newtonsCradle body
*/
Example.newtonsCradle.newtonsCradle = function(xx, yy, number, size, length) {
    var Composite = Matter.Composite,
        Constraint = Matter.Constraint,
        Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

    var newtonsCradle = Composite.create({ label: 'Newtons Cradle' });

    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        var separation = 1.9,
            circle = Bodies.circle(xx + i * (size * separation), yy + length, size, 
                { inertia: Infinity, restitution: 1, friction: 0, frictionAir: 0, slop: size * 0.02 }),
            constraint = Constraint.create({ pointA: { x: xx + i * (size * separation), y: yy }, bodyB: circle });

        Composite.addBody(newtonsCradle, circle);
        Composite.addConstraint(newtonsCradle, constraint);
    }

    return newtonsCradle;
};

The full code is freely accessible through their github page or the provided link > code icon.

Related: https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/21, https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/256. Why do you need the simulation to go on forever? Could you record the positions of one "round" of simulation, then play them back in an animation loop?

I have played around with different parameters (including frictionStatic) and my best guess is that this is due to the imperfections of the simulation. I suspect that it just doesn't use the equations suitable for the calculations of the Newton's Cradle model.
For example, there is the body.slop parameter, which is not something that exists in physics.
It is a generic physics engine and it will not simulate all of physics perfectly.
For a more long-running simulation you could set frictionAir: -0.002, for the circles as a hack.
